# Open Source projects for Video on Demand server application

Tags: .net, video, streaming, video-streaming, vlc

What are the preferable software platform and open-source projects for building Video on Demand server application?

I have played a little with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/). But it has not decent support for .NET platform. Maybe there are other alternatives better suited for my purpose. If it is relevant, a client side is the Android device. Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: can't you rely on html 5 and its video support ?

Comment: Hardly. I think, I need something more specific for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Feng](http://lscube.org/feng) is an open source RTSP server that works for VoD. I don't see what .NET has to do with video on demand, maybe you should say what your purpose is so someone could suggest something more suitable.

Comment: Thanks. It looks interesting. What I need is to be able easily customize and optimize a founded solution for my purposes. Since, I am .NET developer, a library with .NET API is preferable for me.